# Writing SQL query in C# with ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, sql, excel-dna

I'm writing a function that takes a file path and SQL query(both as strings) as returns the results of the query. Quite easy to do in VBA as the return type is simply Variant. Since I can't return a DataTable using ExcelDNA, I was wondering what is the correct way of doing this?

Would the return type be a 2D object array? e.g.

```
public static object[,] RunQueryCS(string SQLStatement, string FilePath)
```

If yes, then what is the recommended method for populating the return array? Should I just iterate over the entire table and populate each cell one at a time? Example code below (dt is the DataTable),

```
        object[,] ret = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count + 1];

        int rowCount = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            rowCount++;
            int colCount = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                colCount++;
                ret[rowCount, colCount] = row[col]; 
            }
        }
```

Is this the most efficient to achieve this?

Comment: What would you have put in the 'Variant' that you return from VBA?

Comment: Govert, I've replied to you on the Excel DNA Google Group.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the entire table is the method I've chosen to use.